# How to open Target Activity using firebase Notification in android application?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

successfully send notification on my apps , but can't open target activity.
when i click my notification it's open MainActivity.java. I want to open my target activity.
Thanks.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Please post your code So we can give you suggestion how it will fix.

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) says:

> When your app is in the background, Android directs notification
>   messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the
>   app launcher by default.
>
> This includes messages that contain both notification and data payload
>   (and all messages sent from the Notifications console). In these
>   cases, the notification is delivered to the device's system tray, and
>   the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your
>   launcher Activity.

So, you can check the extras in `onCreate()` method of your `MainActivity.java`  and if it's from firebase, then open the target activity and finish the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

Add `"click_action": "ACTIVITY_FILTER_NAME"` in `notification` array to your JSON payload from the firebase console.

Sample Json payload:

```
{
  "registration_ids": [
    "XXX",
    ...
  ],
  "data": {
    "id_offer": "100"
  },
  "notification": {
    "title": "This is the Title",
    "text": "This is the message"
    "click_action": "ACTIVITY_FILTER_NAME"
  }
}
```

Then, add the filter to the activity you want to handle the notification by default using

```
<activity
android:name=".MyNotificationHandler">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="ACTIVITY_FILTER_NAME" />        
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

This will open the target activity and also passes on the payload of notification